# How to combine two arrays in php inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have product options that came from database and I want to merge all the values by same product_id .

I'm using a foreachloop.

```
stdClass Object(
    [id] => 22
    [product_id] => 48
    [values] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 81
            [option_id] => 22
            [name] => Black
            [value] => black 
        )
    )
),
stdClass Object(
    [id] => 10
    [product_id] => 50
    [values] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 33
            [option_id] => 10
            [name] => L
            [value] => l 
        ),
        [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 34
            [option_id] => 10
            [name] => M
            [value] => m 
        )
    )   
),
stdClass Object(
    [id] => 24
    [product_id] => 48
    [values] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 98
            [option_id] => 11
            [name] => X
            [value] => x 
        ),
        [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 99
            [option_id] => 11
            [name] => XL
            [value] => xl 
        ),
        [2] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 100
            [option_id] => 11
            [name] => XLL
            [value] => xll 
        )
    )
)
```

I want to combine these array by same `product_id` and get output like :

```
stdClass Object(
    [id] => 22
    [product_id] => 48
    [values] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 81
            [option_id] => 22
            [name] => Black
            [value] => black 
        ),
        [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 98
            [option_id] => 11
            [name] => X
            [value] => x 
        )
        [2] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 99
            [option_id] => 11
            [name] => XL
            [value] => xl 
        ),
        [3] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 100
            [option_id] => 11
            [name] => XLL
            [value] => xll 
        )
),
stdClass Object(
    [id] => 10
    [product_id] => 50
    [values] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 33
            [option_id] => 10
            [name] => L
            [value] => l 
        ),
        [1] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 34
            [option_id] => 10
            [name] => M
            [value] => m 
        )
    )   
)
```

I'm using foreach loop , How to do this inside foreach loop ?
I want to merge values of same product_id. What is the best way to do this ?

My code is:

```
foreach($data['products'] as $pro){
    foreach($pro->options as $opt){
        debug($opt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u add ur code?? May be there is a small correction needed.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju  
My code is: 
  foreach($data['products'] as $pro){
   foreach($pro->options as $opt){
    debug($opt);
   }
  }

Comment: u have to check the product id. If they are same, then merge the arrays... May be update your question with ur code.

Comment: What about the `id`, do you just want to pick the first value you encounter, or …?

Comment: @CBroe: I just want to combine values of same products.

Comment: Not what I meant … `[id] => 22` at the very beginning of your desired output, by what logic do you want it to pick _that one_, and not `[id] => 24`, which also occurs for product=48 later on? This is something you need to _specify_ upfront.

Comment: @CBroe : Don't care about id, I just want to combine these array by same product_id, which i've mentioned above in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this :

**1/ Your data**

```
$array = /* array with all your product obj */;

// Create your new result array
$result = array();
```

**2/ The foreach loop**

```
// Loop throught all your object
foreach ($array as $obj) {

    // Your current product id
    $current_product_id = $obj->product_id;

    // The values of this product
    $current_product_values = $obj->values;

    // Loop through all the value of the product
    foreach ($current_product_values as $value) {

        // Add those value to your result array for the current product id
        $result[$current_product_id][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Is it what you are looking for?